# NSString to NSDate with format conversation issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I've already searched StackOverflow.com for an answer to this question, still without any success. Already looked here:

[iOS - Converting time and date to user time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298010/ios-converting-time-and-date-to-user-time-zone)

[Date Format - time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922971/date-format-time-zone)

[Get current iPhone device timezone date and time from UTC-5 timezone date and time iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504843/get-current-iphone-device-timezone-date-and-time-from-utc-5-timezone-date-and-ti)

[IOS how to set date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098647/ios-how-to-set-date-format)

Nothing of those worked.

---

So I have this NSString date format: `2014-05-07T10:28:52.000Z` trying to convert it to NSDate, this is what I'm using:

```
+ (NSDate*)stringToDate:(NSString*)string format:(NSString*)format
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];
    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
}
```

This is how I'm using it:

```
NSDate *date = [AppUtils stringToDate:youtube.postDate format:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
```

I've also tried those formats:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ZZZ
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.ss.ZZZ
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.ssZZZ
```

How could I convert it to NSDate successfully?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the current result ? and have you an exemple of what can be `youtube.postDate` ?

Comment: You have forgotten to tell us what happens.  Also you quote other stackoverflow questions and mention they don't help, and yet your code   doesn't even set a time zone, so I don't think you've actually read/understood those other questions.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ss.ZZZ`?

Comment: I did read and tried other options, but none of them worked for me. Also this is not the first time I'm using `NSDateFormatter` and I still have no clue why it doesn't work.

Comment: if the date format is fixed what I do is replace `T` by `space` and replace `Z` by `blank` and do formatting...

Comment: I've edited my question and added some other formats that I've used. Actually I've tried almost every combination there is - still not working.

Comment: @KIDdAe I've written in the question what the result should be `2014-05-07T10:28:52.000Z ` - this is the result - always with this format.

Comment: @YossiTsafar : see my answer is working.. Edit 3 with ur case... Edit 2 with my case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date format is fixed, what I do is below.

```
Replace T by space
Replace Z by blank
```

And then do formatting...

```
NSString *dateReceivedInString = @"2014-05-07T10:28:52.000Z";
dateReceivedInString = [dateReceivedInString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
dateReceivedInString = [dateReceivedInString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Z" withString:@""];
```

Now do the formatting using

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

### Edit 1

If you want to work with your case, use below

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
```

### Edit 2

I tried this and it is working.

```
NSString *dateReceivedInString = @"2014-05-07T10:28:52.000Z";
dateReceivedInString = [dateReceivedInString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T" withString:@" "];
dateReceivedInString = [dateReceivedInString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Z" withString:@""];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
NSLog(@"ddddd====%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateReceivedInString]);
```

### Edit 3

To make working with your case use below.

```
NSString *dateReceivedInString = @"2014-05-07T10:28:52.000Z";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSLog(@"ddddd====%@", [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateReceivedInString]);
```

Comment: what is different between add space and leave blank ?

Comment: Thanks, but I did it like this: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.ss Z` and like this: `yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm.ss` still not working.

Comment: `2014-05-0710:28:52` is better or `2014-05-07 10:28:52` in **READ**??

Comment: @YossiTsafar : No I don't meant in expression.. I meant in the date string that you received...

Comment: I did as you said, removed all those unused characters, not it looks like that: `2009-06-30 12:40:53` but still when trying to format it, still i've got `nil` in result.

Comment: @YossiTsafar : it is happening because you missed milliseconds completely... see my Edit 2. its working now...

Comment: Finally edit 3 is working for me. Thanks alot man! really thank you so much!

Comment: @YossiTsafar : welcome... to avoid such pains I go with edit 2, which always works with me...

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 methods that I use to convert `RFC3339 Date string` to `NSDate`,
And also Method for converting `NSDate` to `RFC3339 Date string`

**Method for converting RFC3339 Date string to NSDate**

```
+ (NSDate *)dateForRFC3339DateTimeString:(NSString *)rfc3339DateTimeString
{    
    NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'"];
    [rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    // Convert the RFC 3339 date time string to an NSDate.
    return [rfc3339DateFormatter dateFromString:rfc3339DateTimeString];}
```

**Method for converting NSDate to RFC3339 Date string**

```
+ (NSString *)RFC3339DateTimeFromDate:(NSDate *)aDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *rfc3339DateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'"];
    [rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    return [rfc3339DateFormatter stringFromDate:aDate];
}
```